# How to output query to file using SQLite3

Tags: sqlite

Is there an equivalent to Oracle's spool for sqlite3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`sqlite3` command-line tool](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html) has the `.output` setting.